# php array in to a drop down box via AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, ajax

I have a couple of drop down boxes. I want the first one to select the category, then an AJAX call is done to a PHP file, that selects the appropriate subcategory array and returns it to the second drop down. Code as below:

The PHP file with the subcategories:

```
    $category = $_POST['category'];

if ($category == "World"){
$subcategory = array('Europe' => "Europe", 'North America' => "North America", 'South America' => "South America");}
    else if ($category == "Sport"){
$subcategory = array("Football , Football", "Rugby , Rugby", "Cricket , Cricket"); }
echo json_encode($subcategory);
```

The AJAX

```
function getsub(category, subcategory) {

var category = document.getElementById('category').value;
$('#subcategory').empty();
$('#subcategory').append("<option>loading...</option>");

//kicking off AJAX
$.ajax({
    url: "../php/subcategory.php",
    type: "POST",
    async: true,
    //this is where we define the data that we will send
    data: {
        category: category,
    },
    success: function (subresults) {
        var subresults = JSON.parse(subresults);
        $('#subcategory').empty();
        $('#subcategory').append("<option value='0'>----Select Sub Categry---</option>");
        $.each(subresults, function (i, item) {

            $('#subcategory').append('<option value="' + subresults[i].id + '">' + subresults[i].name + '</option>');

        });
    },
});
return false;
}
```

The reason I'm doing it this way is because I want to keep the sub-categories on the server side and easy to update without meddling with the code. At the moment, this is outputting the items from the array in to the drop down box, but they are coming through as undefined. Can you help me to output the correct values to the drop down box.

Comment: Does your AJAX call work? Show us some sample data as it is returned in your AJAX call (`console.log(subresults)` right before you parse them in your success function)

Comment: Are you doing a `echo json_encode($subcategory);` in your php code?

Comment: You don't have `id` and `name` keys in your php arrays. You should change to just `subresults[i]`.

Comment: I'm getting the following when I console log {"Europe":"Europe","North America":"North America","South America":"South America"}

Comment: just noticed that I'd cut the echo json_encode($subcategory); off the bottom of the php code.

Comment: Sean, that's worked - thanks. Really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

One thing is that, if you have value and label of the option to be same, you don't need to set the array with `'Europe' => "Europe"` with unnecessary key. Just set the array like this

```
$subcategory = array("Europe", "North America", "South America");
```

And in your JS, set the value and label like this:

```
$.each(subresults, function (i, item) {
     $('#subcategory').append('<option value="' + item + '">' + item + '</option>');
});
```

**But**, if you want to keep separate value and label like this:

```
$subcategory = array('EU' => "Europe", 'NA' => "North America", 'SA' => "South America");
```

Then set the option value and label like this:

```
$.each(subresults, function (i, item) {
     $('#subcategory').append('<option value="' + i + '">' + item + '</option>');
});
```

> Using of `subresults[i]` is unnecessary, because you already have the value as `item`, which is equivalent to `subresults[i]`.

Answer (score 0):

In your AJAX you call for `subresults[i].id` and `subresults[i].name` so you have to use this structure when defining your PHP Arrays :

```
if ($category == "World"){
    $subcategory = array(
        array('id' => "Europe", 'name' => "Europe"),
        array('id' => "North America", 'name' => "North America"),
        array('id' => "South America", 'name' => "South America")
    );}
else if ($category == "Sport"){
    $subcategory = array(
        array('id' => "Football", 'name' => "Football"),
        array('id' => "Rugby", 'name' => "Rugby"),
        array('id' => "Cricket", 'name' => "Cricket")
    ); }
echo json_encode($subcategory);
```